# Cannot trigger click.namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
if (auto != 0){
    var me = this;
    $('.small-arrow-right').on('click.auto', function(event){
        me.next(true)
    });
    slideshow = setInterval(function(){
        $('.small-arrow-right').trigger('click.auto');
    }, auto);
}
```

But it triggers nothing. I have broken my head but still cant see a reason why.

Comment: Did you check the value of auto?

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/2vcx85jy/1/

Comment: Works with this: http://jsfiddle.net/fmk9q73y/

Comment: Are you sure that a. the `if` statement evaluates to true, and b. `auto` contains an int? Check your browser's developer tools/console for JavaScript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working, maybe a semi colon (;) after `me.next(true)`

Live demo : http://jsbin.com/dazalo/4/edit?html,js

*Don't forget to look you browser console*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this because `.small-arrow-right` has another `onclick` handler that just google analytics goal ?